# MySQL запрос в DLE

Tags: php, dle, mysql

В MySQL делаю запрос к `dle_post`, запись успешно добавляется, беру её код

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `1`.`dle_post` (`id`, `autor`, `date`, `short_story`, `full_story`, `xfields`, `title`, `descr`, `keywords`, `category`, `alt_name`, `comm_num`, `allow_comm`, `allow_main`, `approve`, `fixed`, `allow_br`, `symbol`, `tags`, `metatitle`) VALUES (NULL, 'Admin', '2012-10-10 00:00:00', 'Шорт стори', 'фулл стори', '', 'Название', '', '', '1', '', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '', '', '');";
```

И пробую тот же запрос к php
Но ничего не выдает. Разумеется, подключаюсь к базе, выбираю саму базу

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `dle_post` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

 - такой запрос работает
```

А вот верхний нет

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 2):

> В mysql делаю запрос к dle_post,
> запись успешно добавляется, беру её
> код

И как ты его делаешь? из cmd? или в phpmyadmin?

> И пробую тот же запрос к php

Непонятно вообще, ты к php делаешь запрос или к mysql?

если работает такой

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `dle_post` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

но не работает верхний тогда исправить в верхнем самую первую строчку

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `dle_post` (`id`, `autor`, `date`, `short_story`, `full_story`, `xfields`, `title`, `descr`, `keywords`, `category`, `alt_name`, `comm_num`, `allow_comm`, `allow_main`, `approve`, `fixed`, `allow_br`, `symbol`, `tags`, `metatitle`) VALUES (NULL, 'Admin', '2012-10-10 00:00:00', 'Шорт стори', 'фулл стори', '', 'Название', '', '', '1', '', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '', '', '');";
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в DLE, то нужно подключить класс MySQL, создать его экземпляр и делать запрос так:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO `1`.`dle_post` (`id`, `autor`, `date`, `short_story`, `full_story`, `xfields`, `title`, `descr`, `keywords`, `category`, `alt_name`, `comm_num`, `allow_comm`, `allow_main`, `approve`, `fixed`, `allow_br`, `symbol`, `tags`, `metatitle`) VALUES (NULL, 'Admin', '2012-10-10 00:00:00', 'Шорт стори', 'фулл стори', '', 'Название', '', '', '1', '', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '', '', '')");
```